# How to embed unique Id to modelBuilder and load multiple model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have some questions regarding modelBuilder and AggregateSelection.

1. When I load some models using scene builder, can I embed unique Id to model ? it seems the dbId is only meant for a mesh.
2. Is it possible to load multiple SceneBuilder models?. (not just some object in modelbuilder). I want to make a tool that can click an object and able to move it. But what happens is that all objects in the model builder moved.

   ```
    addBox(dbId, position, rotation) {
    this.viewer
      .loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder")
      .then((builder) => {
        this.sceneBuilder = builder;
        return this.sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
          modelNameOverride: "box",
          conserveMemory: false,
        });
      })
      .then((builder) => {
        console.log("model builder created");
        let modelBuilder = builder;
        const box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const boxBuff = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(box);
        this.box = new THREE.Mesh(boxBuff, this.globalMaterial);
        this.box.dbId = dbId;
        modelBuilder.addMesh(this.box);
      });
   }

    addSphere(dbId, position, rotation) {
    this.viewer
      .loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder")
      .then((builder) => {
        this.sceneBuilder = builder;
        return this.sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
          modelNameOverride: "sphere",
          conserveMemory: false,
        });
      })
      .then((builder) => {
        let modelBuilder = builder;
        console.log("model builder created");
        let modelBuilder = builder;
        const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 16);
        const sphereBuff = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(sphere);
        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(boxBuff, this.globalMaterial);
        this.sphere.dbId = dbId;
        modelBuilder.addMesh(this.sphere);
      });
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to assign custom IDs to the actual *model* created using the `SceneBuilder` extension (Forge Viewer assigns sequential numbers to all models automatically) but you can assign custom dbIDs to individual *meshes* exactly as you do in your code snippet, using the `mesh.dbId` property.

And btw. you can easily manipulate individual meshes in the models using the [ModelBuilder#changeFragmentTransform](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ModelBuilder/#changefragmenttransform-fragment-transform-bbox) method. The following two functions insert a box and a sphere to the viewer, and each of these objects will be animated differently:

```js
async function addBoxModel(viewer, dbid, position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), orientation = new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), scale = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)) {
    const sceneBuilder = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
    const modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
        modelNameOverride: 'box',
        conserveMemory: false
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10)),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) })
    );
    mesh.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(position, orientation, scale);
    mesh.dbId = dbid;
    modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);

    // Animate the object, rotating it around the Z axis
    let angle = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        const offset = new THREE.Vector3(100.0 * Math.cos(angle), 100.0 * Math.sin(angle), 0.0);
        const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(offset.add(position), orientation, scale);
        modelBuilder.changeFragmentTransform(mesh, matrix);
        viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
        angle += Math.PI / 50;
    }, 100);
}

async function addSphereModel(viewer, dbid, position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), orientation = new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), scale = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)) {
    const sceneBuilder = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
    const modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
        modelNameOverride: 'box',
        conserveMemory: false
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10.0, 16, 16)),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0) })
    );
    mesh.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(position, orientation, scale);
    mesh.dbId = dbid;
    modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);

    // Animate the object, rotating it around the X axis
    let angle = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        const offset = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 100.0 * Math.cos(angle), 100.0 * Math.sin(angle));
        const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(offset.add(position), orientation, scale);
        modelBuilder.changeFragmentTransform(mesh, matrix);
        viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
        angle += Math.PI / 50;
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Interesting!. Second questions also answered. Can the flashing shadow when updating something be removed? I put buildings and some dynamic moving models and it is quite distracting.

Comment: Yes, you can disable the "ground shadow" in the settings (in the Appearance tab), or programmatically using the Viewer API [setGroundShadow](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setgroundshadow-value): `viewer.setGroundShadow(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what seed CAD software was used to generate the Forge model, the `externalId` property may already contain a suitable unique id.

This is explained from a Revit point of view in the article on [Unique IDs for Forge Viewer Elements](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/08/revit-versus-forge-ids-and-add-in-installation.html#4).